# MysqlDB call TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable python

Tags: python, flask, iterable

I am running a query like:

```
SELECT post_title, post_name FROM wp_posts WHERE post_status='publish' ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 3
```

which outputs information like:

```
ID   post_title       post_name
1    a title here     a-title-here
2    a title here2     a-title-here2
3    a title here3     a-title-here3
```

and trying to call it in `app.py` for flask :

```
@app.route('/', methods=('GET', 'POST'))
def email():
        blogposts = c.execute("SELECT post_title, post_name FROM wp_posts WHERE post_status='publish' ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 3")

        return render_template('index.html', form=form, blogposts=blogposts)
```

In my template, I'm calling `blogposts` like:

```
    {% for blogpost in blogposts %}
    <li><a href="{{blogpost[1]}}">{{blogpost[0]}}</a></li>
    {% else %}
    <li>no content...</li>
    {% endfor %}
```

But Im getting an error of :

```
    {% for blogpost in blogposts %}
TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable
```

What am i doing wrong here?

Comment: how do you get `blogposts` in `email()` ? it seems it is some number, not list or rows.

Comment: See additions above. `blogposts` is literally a query to mysql

Comment: check `print(blogposts)` in `email()` to see what you get.

Comment: I was intending to loop over each of the three rows in the db. can you help with that?

Comment: most database modules has function `fetch()` or `fetchall()` so check if there is `blogposts.fetchall()`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `.execute` calls in Python MySQL (and other databases) connectors do not return the database results directly.  (In this case it is returning the number of matched records).

You have to make a further call to the database driver to retrieve the actual `select` results. The simpler one is the `.fetchall()` method that will return you all selected results as a list.

In short, change your call to  `execute`for these two lines:

```
...
c.execute("SELECT post_title, post_name FROM wp_posts WHERE post_status='publish' ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 3")
blogposts = c.fetchall()
```